# Setting tomcat connectionUploadTimeout in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to try to set the Tomcat [connectionUploadTimeout](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation) property within Spring Boot 2. I'm getting some random non-reproducible `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null` in my server logs.

It's coming from the request input stream, so if I can set this property to a really short duration, then I should be able to replicate it locally.

I've tried

```
server.disableUploadTimeout=false
server.connectionUploadTimeout=5000
```

and

```
server.tomcat.disableUploadTimeout=false
server.tomcat.connectionUploadTimeout=5000
```

and

```
server.tomcat.disable-upload-timeout=false
server.tomcat.connection-upload-timeout=5000
```

but still my 15 seconds requests locally are completing without any time-outs.

The [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-embedded-containers) are not very helpful here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to guess which properties are supported as they're all listed in [an appendix in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). As you can hopefully see, there are no properties for configuring the connection upload timeout or for enabling the upload timeout on a `Connector`. This means that those properties must be configured programatically.

You can configure the `Connector` programmatically using a Tomcat-specific `WebServerFactoryCustomizer`:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
    return (tomcat) -> tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
        if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {
            AbstractHttp11Protocol<?> protocolHandler = (AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector
                    .getProtocolHandler();
            protocolHandler.setDisableUploadTimeout(false);
            protocolHandler.setConnectionUploadTimeout(5000);
        }
    });
}
```