# 504 Gateway Time-out issue in Spring Boot when uploading large file in tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am trying to upload a large CSV file (500MB) file in tomcat server . But everytime I am getting "**504 Gateway Time-out**" error.

I am not getting any issue in catalina.out file

```
**Part of my application.properties file**

async-timeout-ms: 1800000 #AsyncTimeout on the connector.
keepAliveTimeout: 1800000 # KeepAliveTimeout on the nioHandler.
connection-timeout-ms: 1800000 # Connection Timeout on the nioHandler

innodb_strict_mode = 0
GLOBAL max_connections = 1500; 
# ==============================================================

spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=800MB
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize=800MB
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=800MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=800MB
```

The following error occurs in the stacktrace:

```
...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-4)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: dataSource_flashsale:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
```

Comment: Please try to set the connectionUploadTimeout like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307096/setting-tomcat-connectionuploadtimeout-in-spring-boot

Comment: @arnonuem i have tried ... but didnt work out ....

Comment: @arnonuem with small csv file it just work fine !!!

Comment: are there any other errors in stack trace?

Comment: @arnonuem   Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-4)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: dataSource_flashsale:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource

Comment: Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: dataSource_flashsale:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource

Comment: But despite those small CSV file works fine !!

Comment: yeah this error is just a MBean thing.

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: is there an causedBy to this?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-4)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: dataSource_flashsale:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource

Comment: ok then the mbean thing might be relevant

Comment: could you please rename the mbean called datasource into something like datasource-renamed?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the memory settings of the JVM?

Comment: @stdunbar  i have increase the Heap Size                                                  
                                                                 export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms4096m" 
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx8192m" 
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Comment: @arnonuem I already rename it everytime it gives me the same error..!!!